# How does exporting templated C++ classes from shared library work on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, shared-libraries

Under Windows, exporting from DLL a class with `std::vector` or `boost::shared_ptr` fields almost always leads to access violations. Apparently, that's not the case on Linux, and one can import

```
class Test {
public:
     boost::shared_ptr<SomeObscureClass> data;

     // ...
}
```

from a shared library to a program which already links against Boost, and it will all work... But how?

As I understand, the main cause of crashes in Windows case is that both the main program and the shared library have template instances of `boost::shared_ptr<SomeObscureClass>` methods — so, for example, `delete` and static fields get confused, which leads to bad things.

But on Linux it apparently works fine! I've seen at least five different C++ libraries, developed on Linux, which are built into shared libraries, and have `std::` fields, and apparently don't suffer any problems. How does that work?

Comment: The windows behaviour you mentioned is not exactly right. You can export classes containing std components as long as you use the /MD(d) options. This links the c++ runtime dynamically instead of compiling it into your code. The Linux behaviour is similar, you need to link to the .so runtime

Comment: `boost::whatever` is not in VS runtime, and it causes problems. Anyway, runtime just can't have, say, `boost::shared_ptr<SomeObscureClass>::operator*` implemented in it, because it has no knowledge of `SomeObscureClass`.

Comment: You can compile the boost libraries using [macros](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_for_libraries_with_separate_source_code.macros_controlling_shared_library_symbol_visibility) to control the exported interfaces. The issue is of symbol visibility & not of some limitation of the OS. The rule of thumb is if you export a resource acquisition function you must also export the corresponding clean up function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbols related to instantiation of template are in no way different from other symbols.

On Linux, shared libraries all symbols not explicitly made private are exported, so a process will use only the one provided by the "first" library (you may have to pay a little more attention to your options if you want shared libraries use symbols provided by the main executable, but it is possible as well).  You can make symbols explicitly private and have a shared library use the one it provides if you need; in the past you had to play with linker scripts for that, nowadays, gcc provides options and attribute to help fine grained control.

My understanding (but I'm not an expert on Windows, it is just what I read on forums like this one) is that on Windows the default is reversed and all symbols not explicitly made public are private but you can resolve the issue by changing attributes on symbols (I've no clue how easy or hard it is).

Comment: Hmmm. Do I understand it correctly: if, say, a shared lib which uses internally `boost::shared_ptr` is used in a program which doesn't uses Boost at all, it would still work, since it has all needed template instances in it. But if the program did use Boost, that library would not use its own Boost functions, but the ones from the main program?

Comment: Most probably you'll use a shared boost library and instead of including and exporting them in your shared library.  So in both case, symbols from boost will come from the boost library.  What can be present several times (with a coherent one used for the whole program) is generated things like template or inline functions.  (Yes the whole program will have to be compiled with a coherent boost library, that's why you may want to make some symbols private and not provide inline functions for interface related things).

Comment: Shared libraries is not so hard to get right but whatever system you are using, a library must be designed to be shared if you want it to be really usable.  Sadly, I don't know of a good introduction to the subject.